# Using Puppet with complex Nginx VirtualHosts

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, puppet, fastcgi, provisioning

I'm trying to use Puppet and a [Nginx plugin](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx) to manage a virtual host config file. I have everything working, but now that I need to add some rewrite rules I'm running into issues.

I know I can use syntax like the line below to add a simple rule...

`location_cfg_append => { 'rewrite' => '^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent' },`

but I'm totally not getting how to use a slightly more complex set up such as

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example should not be a rewrite at all. It should be the last entry in the `try_files` directive. For instance:

```
server {
    #.....stuff.....
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

Your puppet module seems to support a `try_files` parameter in `nginx::resource::vhost`.

Comment: I was not aware of the try_files directive in Nginx, and using the line you provided I was able to get everything working again.

Comment: Using the Puppet module I linked to in my question, this is what it looks like in the manifest. `try_files           => [ '$uri $uri/ /index.php' ]`